# Where can I find more information about D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG and DNDEBUG flags?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-flags

I am trying to understand D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG and DNDEBUG flags.

But I can't find information about them.

Can anyone explain what they do? and where can I read more about them?

Comment: It's actually `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` and `NDEBUG` without the `D`.

Comment: I gave you the real names, now they are easily searchable in the web.

Answer (score 9):

Both use [-D](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) which defines the macro given after the `D`.

When `NDEBUG` is defined, [assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) does not check its argument.

When `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` is defined, it activates [debug mode](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc%2B%2B/manual/debug_mode_using.html) in `libstdc++` (causing `libstdc++` to perform checks on various operations).

Comment: So you write `-DNDEBUG` and `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` when conjuring compiler via command line, right?

Comment: @shuhalo: Yes, if you want the `NDEBUG` and `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` macros to be defined during compilation.